# Github Actionsでのプルリク時にイベントを実行したい。

Tags: github, github-actions

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Github Actionsでのプルリク時にイベントを実行したい。
プルリク時にJiraと連携して、Jiraのボードにあるissueを移動させたい。

### 出来ていること

push時は、Jiraのissueの移動に成功している。

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - '*'
    - '!develop'

name: Transition Issue

jobs:
  test-transition-issue:
    name: Transition Issue
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Login
      uses: atlassian/gajira-login@master
      env:
        JIRA_BASE_URL: ${{ secrets.JIRA_BASE_URL }}
        JIRA_USER_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.JIRA_USER_EMAIL }}
        JIRA_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.JIRA_API_TOKEN }}

    # プッシュされたコミットに記載された課題キーを抽出する    
    - name: Find in commit messages
      id: find
      uses: atlassian/gajira-find-issue-key@master
      with:
        string: ${{ github.event.ref }}

    # 課題キーが特定できればJiraに対してトランジションを発行　    
    - name: Transition issue
      uses: atlassian/gajira-transition@master
      # 課題キーが含まれていなければスルー
      if: ${{ steps.find.outputs.issue }}
      with:
        # 前のステップのアウトプットを参照
        issue: ${{ steps.find.outputs.issue }}
        transition: "In progress"
```

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

プルリク時は、上手く行かない。

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - 'develop'

name: Transition Issue

jobs:
  test-transition-issue:
    name: Transition Issue
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Login
      uses: atlassian/gajira-login@master
      env:
        JIRA_BASE_URL: ${{ secrets.JIRA_BASE_URL }}
        JIRA_USER_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.JIRA_USER_EMAIL }}
        JIRA_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.JIRA_API_TOKEN }}

    # プッシュされたコミットに記載された課題キーを抽出する    
    - name: Find in commit messages
      id: find
      uses: atlassian/gajira-find-issue-key@master
      with:
        string: ${{ github.event.ref }}

    # 課題キーが特定できればJiraに対してトランジションを発行　    
    - name: Transition issue
      uses: atlassian/gajira-transition@master
      # 課題キーが含まれていなければスルー
      if: ${{ steps.find.outputs.issue }}
      with:
        # 前のステップのアウトプットを参照
        issue: ${{ steps.find.outputs.issue }}
        transition: "In progress"
```

エラーメッセージ
name: Find in commit messagesにおいて、エラーになる。

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

#### 原因

下記の部分の記述が上手くいっていない。

```
  # プッシュされたコミットに記載された課題キーを抽出する    
  - name: Find in commit messages
    id: find
    uses: atlassian/gajira-find-issue-key@master
    with:
      string: ${{ github.event.ref }}
```

#### 分からないこと

問題の箇所を、どのように修正すれば良いか分からない。
お分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

##参考
[Github Actions と jira を連携してイケイケな開発ライフを実現する](https://qiita.com/maru401/items/bb668edd4f8f1dfc091c)
[Jira Issue Transition](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/jira-issue-transition)

※本質問は別サイトでも回答を募集しております。急ぎで解決策を見つける必要があるためです。何卒ご容赦下さい。
https://teratail.com/questions/366905

Comment: `github.event.ref` の代わりに [`github.base_ref`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62331829/4506703) とするとどうでしょうか。([`pull_request`イベント](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request) には `ref` が存在しないようです)

Comment: refが使えないとのご指摘ありがとうございます。ご共有頂いたURLを参考に、色々試してみましたが依然上手く言っておりません。

Comment: 参考になりそうなIssue [TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined · Issue #24 · atlassian/gajira-find-issue-key](https://github.com/atlassian/gajira-find-issue-key/issues/24)

Comment: ありがとうございます！上手くできました。